# Can't refresh using jQuery.Get() method

Tags: jquery, ajax, get, refresh

I'm using the AJAX method jQuery.Get() because it's really simple to use.
I use this to load pages into a div. But when I change this page that is being loaded and click Refresh. It won't be updated. The only solution is to exit the browser and reopen it and go to the website again. This is really anoying and I wonder if there is a solution to this.

More info on the method:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Code used:

```
function pagina_ophalen(pagina){    
    $.get('paginas/' + pagina + '.html', function(data){
    $('#inlaadcontent').css('display','none');
        $('#inlaadcontent').html(data);
    $('#inlaadcontent').fadeIn("slow");
    });

}
```

Thank you very much.
Dylan

Comment: Sourcecode seems to be correct so far. Do you have any errors in your Firebug/Chrome console? is pagina a valid string?
I personally recommend using Firebug or the Chrome Dev tools for a further look into this issue.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest change you can make to get this working is

```
function pagina_ophalen(pagina){    
    $.get('paginas/' + pagina + '.html',
          { t = new Date().getTime() },    // ADD THIS
          function(data){
            $('#inlaadcontent').css('display','none');
            $('#inlaadcontent').html(data);
            $('#inlaadcontent').fadeIn("slow");
          });
}
```

**What's the difference?**

Your browser is caching the result of the AJAX request because the URL is the same each time. By adding a query parameter that is variable (`?t=xxxxxxx`, based on the current timestamp) you make the browser consider each request as a new one and fetch the page again instead of using the cached result.

If you take a look at the [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function (of which `get` is simply a convenience-targeted subset), you will see that there is a `cache` option you can set. This does exactly what I described above if set to `false`.

Comment: I Understand the problem now, tough using an exact copy of the code you written gives me an error in aptana

Comment: This works

     function pagina_ophalen(pagina){
  
  $.get('paginas/' + pagina + '.html', { name:  Math.random } , 
  
  function(data){
  $('#inlaadcontent').css('display','none');
   $('#inlaadcontent').html(data);
  $('#inlaadcontent').fadeIn("slow");
  });
  
 }

Answer (score 0):

Problem in caching. Try to add random number to your URL:

```
var randomToken = Math.random(); // Or replace if you need
$.get('paginas/' + pagina + '.html' + ? randomToken, function(data) {
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and set cache to false.

$.get() calls $.ajax anyways, so you are skipping a step, and getting the correct result.